# Is there a way to translate products in woocommerce with Polylang, but without duplicating them?

Tags: woocommerce, polylang

I have a wordpress installation with a woocommerce and free version of Polylang plugin. With polylang i can translate, for example, pages and posts - it creates a separate page for some kind of content. And it is good!

But in case of translating my products - i don't want to duplicate products! If i have a page like site.com/shop/iphone11, i want to keep only one product page with only one id, but to have a way to show it's name and description in another language when user selects another in language selector. What can be a solution?